# How to apply filter when one condition is a list of values

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I want to filter the values of data frame (A) which does not meet a a condition. This condition is the content of a column of other data frame (B). So the filtering should return values of the data frame (A) which are not included in the column of the data frme (B). I have found a possible method  to do it without applying the function filter, but I would like to know if it is possible to do something similar using this function. Find below the method without using filter:

```
df<-df[!(df$Wind %in% g_caja$out),]
```

`df$Wind` should be data frame A

`g_caja$out` should be data frame B

Answer (score 2):

The `filter` can use the same logic

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     filter(!Wind %in% g_caja$out)
```

---

Or another option is `anti_join`

```
anti_join(df, g_caja, by = c("Wind" = "out"))
```